# Codigo php se muestra en el navegador

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy realizando un login en php pero al oprimir el submit (ingresar) me muestra  el codigo php en el navegador en vez de ejecutarlo.
Ya configure las variables de entorno pero aun nada sigue sin funcionar.
Estoy usando xampp ultima version y mi archivo esta en htdocs directamente en la carpeta de xampp.

```
<body>
    <!-- Start container login-->
    <div class="limiter border">
        <div class="container-login100  ">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-8 p-b-31 bg-white border ">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="php/Controler.php" method="POST">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49  text-white">
                             <img src="img/gl.png" class="fas fa-laugh-wink" />
                                         </span>
                    <div class="md-form md-outline form-lg">
                        <input id="form-lg" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text">
                        <label for="form-lg">Correo eletronico o teléfono</label>
                        <div class="text-right p-t-8 p-b-31 text-primary">
                            <a class="p-b-31 text-primary" href="#">
                                ¿Has olvidado tu correo ? </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-right p-t-8 p-b-31 text-primary">
                        <div class="mb-4"></div> <a class="text-right p-t-8 p-b-31 text-primary" href="#">
                            Crear cuenta
                            </a>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " name="accion" value="Siguiente">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End container login-->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Your custom scripts (optional) -->

</body>
```

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    echo "si recibe email";
}
else{
    echo "no recibe email";
}
```

Comment: Muchas veces ese error es por el servidor local,¿usas algo como xampp?

Comment: Hola @Charls, si uso xampp la ultima version y la carpeta donde tengo el index.html y el archivo de php esta en htdocs de xampp ya lo echo varias veces asi pero nose no funciona

Comment: Interesante, podrías agregar tu código, para entender mejor el error?

Comment: Está en ejecución el servidor Apache de XAMPP?

Comment: @Eric Si tengo en ejecucion Apache

Comment: y el ?> en Controler.php?

Comment: si ya tienes el Apache ejecuandose tienes que escribir en el navegador "localhost/nombredelacarpeta"

Comment: Hola @StevenCamargo, si ya lo hice de esta manera que me indicas. Incluso tam bien lo hago solo al htdocs y entro directamente desde hay pero de esas formas sigue sin ejecutar el php

Comment: Chicos gracias por las opiniones ya encontre otra solucion y me funciono, en las variabels de entorno agregue de mas \php.exe y funciono

Comment: En la captura de la pantalla estás accediendo al php directamente desde la ruta en disco. Debes acceder desde `http://localhost/ruta/archivo.php`

Comment: intenta crear un Host Virtual Nuevo y en ese directorio agregar tu proyecto php y ya lo abres desde localhost...

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que estás abriendo el archivo como un simple documento por lo que php no lo está interpretando. 
Te puedes dar cuenta por la ruta que aparece en el navegador (Te adjunto imagen). 
Para solucionar esto, nada más debes asegurarte que tu servidor Apache (Xampp en este caso) esté corriendo, y luego llamar a tu documento a través de la ruta localhost/{nombre_de_tu_documento.php} o 127.0.0.1/{nombre_de_tu_documento.php}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No se si esto será una solución pero recuerda que todos los códigos tienen una etiqueta de cierre. En php es:

```
?>
```

Creo que tu problema podría ser por eso pero no estoy seguro, de todas formas, te lo dejo por aquí, haber si te ayuda.

Comment: Las comillas finales se pueden omitir [enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 0):

2023: Xampp funciona si desde localhost se llama un archivo php.
El problema es que si en navegador deseas ver el código fuente de la página cargada desde localhost, se muestran las consultas y todo lo que está en PHP.
Las etiquetas están bien cerradas, domino bien el lenguaje, pero el Xampp me deja perplejo al mostrar el código PHP.
Creo que probaré Wamp porque es increible que pase esto.
Este código parcial se ve desde "ver código fuente de la página" en Chrome.
Se muestra la variable $timestamp  !!

Quité el ejemplo de código porque al cargqr este comentario no se muestra la parte con php :)

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/379448)